# Solving a homogenous, weighted LSE problem

Tags: least-squares, constraints, homogeneous-equation

I search the non trivial solution for the system 
$\bf{Ax}=\bf{b} = \bf{0}$, where the equations are weighted with the matrix $\bf{W}$.

I found 2 different approaches for each part, which I would like to combine, but I am not sure how to do this.

1. Solving the homogeneous system:
   Calculate the generalized Eigenmatrix of $\bf{V} = \bf{A^TA}$, where the vector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue is a solution.
2. Using classical LSE including weighting:
   $\bf{x} = \bf{(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWb}$

I think another option is to change the problem to LSE with constraint ($\bf{||x||} = 1$} for example). My problem with that is, that I need to implement this efficiently on an microcontroller. So far I couldn't find a comprehensible algorithm for that (certainly due to my limited knowledge).
The advantage of 1. is the easy implementation.

So finally, the questions:

A) Is there a way to combine approach 1 and 2?
B) If not, what is the solution path for LSE with constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with an intermediate step posted  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/709683/355368) by Matt L.

Following his explanation, the weighted error $e$ is:

$e = \bf{W(Ax-b)}$

leading to the system of equations:

$\bf{A^TW^TWAx}= \bf{A^TW^TWb}$

with $\bf{b}=\bf{0}%$ we have:

$\bf{A^TW^TWAx}= \bf{0}$

to which we can apply the solution 1) from the question, calculating the generalized eigenmatrix from V with:

$V = \bf{A^TW^TWA}$

The eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue is now the solution.