# How to solve conditional least square?

Tags: least-squares, weighted-least-squares

I'm studying least square, so I can calculate optimal solution at overdetermined system. [weighted least square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709602/when-solving-an-overdetermined-linear-system-is-it-possible-to-weight-the-influ)

But when some conditions are given, I can't calculate optimal solution(sub?) 
For example,

- $ax+by>c$,
- $a_1x+b_1y>c_1$,
- $a_2x+b_2y>c_2$
- ...

10 functions 
 x and y are bigger than a10x+b10y=c10 
 [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v1sZ.png)
How to solve this? (I want find a optimal point that makes all anX+bnY are bigger than cn)

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you mean how to solve in practice? It is a quadratic optimization problem and there are solvers for that.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks! Could you link sites for me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_optimization